# Refresh NSconnection from applicationDidBecomeActive:method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

My iPhone app is location based app. It finds current location and display it's own details through `NSURLConnection` method. Now I want to refresh this details when app becomes active from Background. I used refresh button which works good. So call the refresh function from `-applicationDidBecomeActive:method`. It get refresh for current location details successfully. But it is not refreshing the other places details.
If i changed the current location to other location the `-applicationDidBecomeActive:` calls refresh for current location only there is no change in view screen. How can i solve this and I want to get refresh for all places?

Delegate method:

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.viewController refresh];//calls refresh method 
}
```

viewController method:

```
-(void)refresh
{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.placedetail.name);
    [self displays:self.placedetail];
}
```

Placedetails instance has latitude and longitude of place using can get details of particularplce. Fist time it is current location.

```
-(void)displays:(model *)place
{
    self.placedetail=place;
    NSString *strs=[@"http requst"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strs]];
    NSLog(@"%@",request);
    self.reqTimeZone=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [self.reqTimeZone start]; 
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you should write code in this delegate..

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{
```

[self.viewController refresh];

}